# Issue when executing shell script in php

Tags: php, shell, unix, shell-exec

I have developed one webpage using PHP . I need to run shell scripts through the php code. I was able to do the same via below method :

```
shell_exec('cd shell_scripts;./ipCheck.sh');
```

ipCheck.sh is like below :

```
SO_IP=$(lxc list SO-ub | awk 'FNR== 4 {print $6 }')

b=10.12.130.2

echo "The IP is $SO_IP .."

echo "The IP is $b"
```

When I run the php page , I could see like the first echo statement is coming blank. `SO_IP` is coming as blank. No IP is showing , where as `b` contains 10.12.130.2 .

When am running the shell script through command terminal like `./ipCheck.sh`, then SO_IP have the IP . Running through PHP is making the problem.

Please help on this issue.
Why shell execution via php is not working properly.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added www-data to lxc group?

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Where should i add www-data. Also as i mentioned when i run the script through command terminal the SO_IP is there.

Comment: `sudo usermod --append --groups lxd www-data`

Comment: Once you get that working use `lxc list SO-ub --format json` instead then your have the data in json format, much better. ;p

Comment: Thanks for the response . I tried that . It still the same old behaviour. :(

Comment: Do you have the hashbang in your bash/sh script? try with full path, `/usr/bin/lxc` and `/usr/bin/awk`, it should work ive just tested it, also if you want to do more then just get the IP address, look into using a lib to talk to the lxd api instead, its more flexible and covers all endpoints. here's one I built as an [php extention](https://github.com/lxc-systems/lxd), or one in [php](https://github.com/ashleyhood/php-lxd) or you could use even use `lxc query -X GET -d '' /1.0/containers/SO-ub` basically your limited in what you can do if you dont use the API

Answer (score 0):

Running the below function solved the issue:

function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)

Thanks for all the response.